# Upload files to server with PHP friendly names and parse them

Tags: php, regex, file-upload, uploadify

I'm trying to upload files to server using [Uploadify script](http://www.uploadify.com/) and then show them using PHP on the website, in the form of "www.example.com/directory-of-upload/file.mp3".

It works fine, until i upload files that contain characters such as commas,quotes etc. Then the php code breaks.

For instance, when i try to parse the file URL as a parameter in a flash player, it looks like this:
`<param name="flashvars" value="soundFile=http://localhost/public_html/content/plugins/post_audio/uploadi‌​fy-local/uploads/song,+one.dad'a;-A.b!@.mp3&amp;titles=song,+one.dad'a;-A.b!@&amp;playerID=audioplayer_song,+one.dad'a;-A.b!@">`
and the file doesn't play. I guess it has something to do with these characters (commas,quotes..)

How should i fix this issue? Is reg ex the only solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Breaks" how?  Show the code, show the error, describe the observed behavior, etc.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (it's been a while since I've done this, and I don't have a handy way to test it right now), but I would imagine it should be UrlEncoded or HtmlEncoded or something to that effect.  (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)  If you're not encoding things properly, your application may be susceptible to SQL Injection or XSS attacks.

Comment: For example, Wordpress using this for cleaning uploaded files from invalid chars : `preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fArr=explode('.',$_FILES['fname']['name']);
$fname=clean(implode('',array_slice($fArr,0,-1,false)));
$ex=clean(implode('',array_slice($fArr,-1,1)));
$file_name=$fname.".".$ex;

function clean($str) {
    $strArr=array();
    $strArr=explode(' ',$str);
    foreach ($strArr as $key=>$val) {
        if (strlen($strArr[$key])==0) {
        unset($strArr[$key]);
        }
    }
    $strArr=array_map('strtolower',$strArr);
    $str=implode(' ',$strArr);
    $str=preg_replace("/\W+/i","",$str);

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use preg replace to remove the charactors your dont want
, you probably want something like this http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10291707